# Deploying Docker project on GitLab fails with 137 exit code?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to deploy a Dockerized Angular/Node.js project on GitLab via Pipelines.

The issue is, once the build gets to `ng build --prod`, the build is stuck there for several minutes, before failing with an `exit code of 137`.

[image]]
[image]

`Service 'client' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build-prod' returned a non-zero code: 137`

**GitLab CI/CD config:**

```
image: docker:latest

services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - deploy

deploy-live:
    stage: deploy
    only: 
        - develop
    script:
        - docker-compose -f client/docker-compose.yml up -d
    when: manual
```

**client/Dockerfile**

```
# STAGE 1 - Build app

# Use node 4.4.5 LTS
FROM node:10.16.3 as client

# Copy files to container
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN ls

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build-prod # Build fails when it reaches this part

FROM nginx

COPY --from=client /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

**client/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    links:
      - server
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

When I try to build this locally, everything works fine. Could this be a memory issue on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still investigating, but so far, the build is able to succeed after these changes:

- Use `node:12-alpine` (actually this just produced a different error message, but essentially still the same error -> out of memory)
- Upgrade the server RAM to 2GB from 1GB